# How to calculate the probability of the occurrence of an event over multiple attempts (1% chance over 10 tries)?

Tags: r, statistics

A probability of occurrence of p=0.01, then we would calculate 1−(1−p)^10. I get 1−(1−0.01)=1−(0.99)^10 which is about 9.6%.

How i can do the same with R using a vector (1:10), a **function from Package stats** and plot the result?

I tried this, but i got wrong results:

```
plot(dbinom(1 , 1:300, 0.01))
```

Comment: What are the two axes for your plot? Right now, you are running plot(a single vector). Your initial example could be done like `1 - dbinom(10, 10, .99)`, btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
p <- 0.01
sapply( 1:10, function(x) 1−(1−p)^x)
# [1] 0.01000000 0.01990000 0.02970100 0.03940399 0.04900995 0.05851985 0.06793465 0.07725531 0.08648275 0.09561792
```

or

```
sapply( 1:10, function(x) ( 1−(1−p)^x )*100)
# [1] 1.000000 1.990000 2.970100 3.940399 4.900995 5.851985 6.793465
# [8] 7.725531 8.648275 9.561792
```

or this vectorized form inside parenthesis

```
1−(1−p)^(1:10)
# [1] 0.01000000 0.01990000 0.02970100 0.03940399 0.04900995 0.05851985
# [7] 0.06793465 0.07725531 0.08648275 0.09561792
```

with `dbinom`

```
1 - dbinom(x = 1:10, size = 1:10, prob = 1-p)
```

Comment: Their homework says to use a function from package stats.

Comment: That's my impression, anyways ... otherwise seems like a weird condition to put into a question.

Comment: `na.omit()` is a function in the package `stats`, so `na.omit(1−(1−p)^(1:10))` fulfills the requirement.

Comment: @Gregor I am confused with the requirement though. why `na.omit()` here?

Comment: I'm poking fun at the arbitrariness and vagueness of the "use a function in the stats package" requirement. I'm sure that `dbinom` is the intended solution, but OP had already figured out the mathematical formula so `dbinom` isn't needed. I just skimmed the contents of the stats package and `na.omit` jumped out at me as a function that wouldn't modify this result. It does nothing but fill the requirement that a `stats` function is used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the goal here is to get you to use one of the "statisical distribution" functions in pkg:stats. If you look at the help page for various distributions, say `dpoisson` (Poisson), `dhyper` (hypergeometric), `dgeom` (geometric), and `dbinom` (binomial), see more at `?Distributions`:

```
 dpois: p(x) = λ^x exp(-λ)/x!
 dhyper: p(x) = choose(m, x) choose(n, k-x) / choose(m+n, k)
 dgeom: p(x) = p (1-p)^x
 dgeom: p(x) = choose(n, x) p^x (1-p)^(n-x)
```

To my eyes, the `dgeom` looks closest to your candidate expression and only needs to be divided by p to be equivalent. In fact, if you then use it to calculate the probabilities of seeing events after 1:10 trials it's just:

```
1-dgeom( 1:10, prob=0.01)/0.01
[1]  0.01000000 0.01990000 0.02970100 0.03940399 0.04900995 0.05851985 0.06793465 0.07725531 0.08648275 0.09561792
```

And you can check against your formula:

```
all.equal( 1-(0.99)^(1:10), 1-dgeom( 1:10, prob=0.01)/0.01)
[1] TRUE
```

Now whether this is actually the desired answer might be up in the air. I suspect that you were supposed to find a distribution which would exactly deliver these values without dividing by the probability value. For instance, the probability of *any* event would be equal to the sum of the probabilities of n events whenever n was greater than or equal to 1. Since the probability of n events is given by the density of the Poisson distribution, the desired answer might just be:

```
sum(dpois(1:10, 0.01) )
[1] 0.009950166
```

This is almost the same as the complement of the probability of zero events:

```
1-dpois(0, 0.01) 
[1] 0.009950166
```

The Poisson distribution is often used when modeling count data. Poisson regression uses that distribution as its error basis and the logarithmic link.

I found your description of the problem somewhat ambiguous, so I'm offering what I think might be helpful, but leaving up to you to decide the "right answer" and what the right justification might be.

Answer (score 0):

I was bothered by the fact that the dpois strategy was deriving a very low probability, lower even than what we would expect for a single trial. I'm thinking that the suggestion to sue the `dbinom` function is correct, but I came around to that position by a series of interactions at the R console that might be useful. The probability of all length-10 trials having no occurrences is just:

```
(.99)^(10)*(.01)^(0)
#[1] 0.9043821
```

We can get the probability of each of the possible outcomes by using a sequence in the exponent position of that expression:

```
 (.99)^(10:0)*(.01)^(0:10)
 #[1] 9.043821e-01 9.135172e-03 9.227447e-05 9.320653e-07 9.414801e-09 9.509900e-11 9.605960e-13
 #[8] 9.702990e-15 9.801000e-17 9.900000e-19 1.000000e-20
```

Likewise we can use the `dbinom` fn to look at the probability of 0 occurrences (and the results agree):

```
dbinom(0, 10, .01)
[1] 0.9043821
```

However, when I tried comparing the results using the binomial function to those using the formula you offered I ran into difficulties:

```
> dbinom(1, 10, .01)
[1] 0.09135172
> (.99)^(9)*(.01)^(1)
[1] 0.009135172
```

That's because the binomial distribution is defined as:

```
p(x) = choose(n, x) p^x (1-p)^(n-x)
```

So the probability of exactly one occurrence in 10 trials is:

```
 choose(10, 1) *.99^(9) *(0.01)^(1)
[1] 0.09135172
```

I'm still leaving it to you to complete the task since it's homework.